# Календарь в своем приложении под ios

Tags: xcode, календарь, ios, objective-c, ios7

Подскажите как сделать кастомный календарь в своем приложении? И, пожалуйста, если вы не знаете, не пишите сюда что-то типа `NSCalendar` или что-то в этом роде! Все знают, что там нужен `NSCalendar` и `NSDateComponents`. Вопрос: как это сделать и второй вопрос - как правильно это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что косается второго вопроса то я бы поискал  изначально [здесь](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=Calendar)
Что косается первого вопроса, то я бы изучил то что скачал во втором вопросе

Answer (score 1):

На `github` есть довольно много примеров как сделать календарь.
Самый простой - [CKCalendar](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar).
Я его сам брал и кастомизировал как мне было нужно.
Вот уже понавороченней - [ABCalendarPicker](https://github.com/k06a/ABCalendarPicker).
Вам никто не скажет как от начала и до конца сделать календарь, пишите конкретные вопросы.

Comment: ссылки битые

Comment: У меня открываются прекрасно ссылки.